# Why are the json data I request is coming as html?

Tags: node.js, json, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm working on a small vue project. The data is in json files within the backend folder. I deployed api to heroku. Data is coming in properly and I can print when working in Local; but when I deploy it to vercel, a structure like in the project's index.html file returns and therefore an error occurs. How can I fix this?

[in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LyWi.png)

[after deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC1WX.png)

Comment: When you build the project, the JSON files are likely renamed and bundled with the rest of the code in `/dist`, or they might not even be included. Make sure you `require` the files somewhere in your code, so webpack will include them.

Comment: Thank you. I found the reason thanks to you; I have configured the proxy in the vue.config.js file; but when I deploy to vercel it doesn't import the config file or it doesn't work properly. Therefore, it sends requests to itself instead of api. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Good day!